# Mongoimport command not working in windows

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport, mongoexport

As per below command used connected host but documents not imported what is the reason

```
H:\Desktop\Downloads\bin>mongoimport.exe  --port 27017 --db sample -c test1 --type JSON --file H:\Desktop\Downloads\MongoBD\dumps\test.json
2021-08-04T23:27:25.815+0530    connected to: mongodb://localhost:27017/
2021-08-04T23:27:25.816+0530    0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

I used DB and Collection 4 documents consisting.

```
rs1:PRIMARY> use sample
switched to db sample
rs1:PRIMARY> db.test1.find().count()
4
rs1:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: Maybe use option `--verbose`. How did you create the JSON file? How does it look like?

Comment: Where should i use --verbose please let me know mongoimport command line

Comment: Hi Team, Any one can help here

Comment: Do you really ask how to put option `--verbose` to your mongoimport.exe? Did you ever consult the documentation?

Comment: Yes, would you please let me know complete command how to take mongoimport by using --verbose

Comment: It's a joke - isn't it? `mongoimport.exe --verbose --port 27017 --db sample -c test1 --type JSON --file H:\Desktop\Downloads\MongoBD\dumps\test.json` Did you consult the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongoimport/#std-option-mongoimport.--help)?

Comment: I did used --verbose but no luck

Comment: H:\Desktop\Downloads\bin>mongoimport.exe  --port 27017 --db sample -c test1 --type JSON --file "H:\Desktop\Downloads\MongoBD\dumps\test.json" --verbose
2021-08-16T20:58:57.718+0530    using write concern: &{majority false 0}

Comment: 2021-08-16T20:58:57.748+0530    filesize: 0 bytes
2021-08-16T20:58:57.748+0530    using fields:
2021-08-16T20:58:57.748+0530    connected to: mongodb://localhost:27017/

Comment: 2021-08-16T20:58:57.748+0530    ns: sample.test1
2021-08-16T20:58:57.750+0530    connected to node type: replset
2021-08-16T20:58:57.750+0530    0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import

Comment: Please put additional information in your question instead of comment. And please answer my other question: How did you create the JSON file? How does it look like?

Comment: If i mentioned mongoimport query anything wrong,  then please let me know correct query how to use mongoimport command  take below DB and collection rs1:PRIMARY> use sample
switched to db sample
rs1:PRIMARY> db.test1.find().count()
4

Comment: Finally , i got it  source file  consisting  security reason. hence unable to  import